# How to make the activity change color in material design (Lollipop)

Tags: android, html, web, material-design

How do I make an website change the activity bar color like the following exemple:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your web page add :

```
<meta name="theme-color" content="#db5945">
```

read more from [here](http://updates.html5rocks.com/2014/11/Support-for-theme-color-in-Chrome-39-for-Android).